# Neo4j error when trying to use SET += when loading csv file in python

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm loading csv file to Neo4j using python. My loading code look like this:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("connection", auth=("name", "password"))

def add_data(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/DataMap.csv' AS Map \
    MERGE (source {node_name: Map.source}) \
    MERGE (destination {node_name: Map.destination}) \
    MERGE (source)-[:FEEDS_INTO]->(destination)")

def add_other(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data \
        Match (n {node_name: Data.dane}) \
        MERGE (system {system_name: Data.system}) \
        MERGE (scope {scope_name: Data.scope}) \
        MERGE (process {process_name: Data.process}) \
        MERGE (owner {owner_name: Data.owner}) \
        MERGE (n)-[:UNDER_SYSTEM]->(system) \
        MERGE (system)-[:UNDER_SCOPE]->(scope) \
        MERGE (n)-[:HAS_PROCESS]->(process) \
        MERGE (owner)-[:IS_OWNER_OF]->(n) ")

def add_data_properties(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data \
    MATCH (n {node_name: Data.dane }) \
    SET n.system += Data.system \
    SET n.scope += Data.scope \
    SET n.process += Data.process \
    SET n.owner += Data.owner")

with driver.session() as session:
    session.write_transaction(add_data)
    session.write_transaction(add_other)
    session.write_transaction(add_data_properties)
driver.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input '+': expected whitespace, comment, '(', '.' or '=' (line 1, column 147 (offset: 146))
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data     MATCH (n {node_name: Data.dane })     SET n.system += Data.system     SET n.scope += Data.scope     SET n.process += Data.process     SET n.owner += Data.owner"                                                                                                                                              ^}
```

But when I'm using for example SET n.system = Data.system everything is ok.
Does anybody have any idea how to fix this ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you already found and corrected the error. If you want to set the property `system` on node `n` then you want to do

```
SET n.system = Data.system
```

if you want to update the node `n` with a map contained in `Data.system` then you want to do

```
SET n += Data.system
```

Comment: Ok. I thought that += not only updates but adds if property doesn't exist. So if that problem sorted itself out I have another little question. Do you know why Neo4J Bloom doesn't show me properties on nodes ? When I click the node I get "This node has no properties" when in Neo4J Browser everythink is working fine and every node has properties. Do I have to use labels instead of properties ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I recommend asking a new question here on SO or on the Neo4j discord at https://discord.com/channels/787399249741479977/787399744955088897